# How can I export all the colums from a spreadsheet into a .txt file per row.

Tags: excel, vba

I have borrowed code on how to export each row of spreadsheet to a separate .txt file and tweaked it to include a title row. How can I have it add all 86 columns in my sheet.

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()

Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim OutputFile As String
Dim CellValue As String
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim CurrentCol As Long
Dim CurrentCharacter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyString As String

LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow
'C:\Regan\regan.xlsm
OutputFile = "C:\Regan\sample" & CurrentRow & ".txt"

Open OutputFile For Output As #1

    CellValue = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value & vbTab & vbCrLf & MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value & vbTab
    'Write #1, CellValue
    Print #1, CellValue

Close #1

Next CurrentRow

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K Ah, sorry I did not understand it that way. My comment preceded your answer btw :)

Comment: @YowE3K Possible, but as far as I remember I comented on the question it was kinda "virgin" :D Anyway, you got the right answer and that's good, I hope the OP will have the decency to accept it and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code loops through each of the 86 columns:

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()
    Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet

    Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    Dim OutputFile As String
    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim CurrentCol As Long
    Dim CurrentCharacter As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyString As String

    LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow
        OutputFile = "C:\Regan\sample" & CurrentRow & ".txt"

        Open OutputFile For Output As #1
        'Write header record
        For CurrentCol = 1 To 86
            Print #1, MyDataWorksheet.Cells(1, CurrentCol).Value & vbTab;
        Next
        Print #1,""
        'Write data record
        For CurrentCol = 1 To 86
            Print #1, MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value & vbTab;
        Next
        Print #1,""

        Close #1
    Next CurrentRow

    MsgBox "Done"    
End Sub
```